# How to use js EXPR with XML in Karate

Tags: karate

I have to modify an xml expression and match it to a json. Below is the code I have written. I need to validate `ind` is true or false. For this, I cannot use `'#boolean'` because `<ns4:ind>true</ns4:ind>` behaves as a string.

**XML File:**

```
<ns9:parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns5:parent">
        <ns4:ind>true</ns4:ind>
        <ns4:description>Some text</ns4:description>
</ns9:parent>
```

**Code:**

```
* def Test = call read ('classpath:Path/Test.xml)
* def Check = $Test/parent
* set Downstream.parent
| path           | value                              |
| ind            | '#?_ == "true" || _== "false"'     |
| description    | $Check/parent/description          |


* def Match = 
"""
{
  "parent": {
    "ind": "true",
    "description": "Some text"
  }
}
"""
* match Match == Downstream
```

Tried with `'#boolean'` as well, doesn't work.

```
    | ind  | '#boolean' |
```

I get below error;

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Test.feature:20 - javascript evaluation failed: '#?_   == "true", <eval>:1:14 Missing close quote '#?_ == "true"
```

Comment: sorry your example is incomplete and has typos. fix it, simplify it and please be more clear

Comment: Done edited; Details provided looks enough to replicate problem.

Comment: were you able to run this code? you are setting values for Downstream without defining it.

Comment: since you can't provide a proper example, please follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @BabuSekaran Yes, the works properly but with an error,  `com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Test.feature:20 - javascript evaluation failed: '#?_ == "true", <eval>:1:14 Missing close quote
'#?_ == "true"` I am calling the xml stored in this file: `* def Test = call read ('classpath:Path/Test.xml)`

Comment: please read your error carefully you need to escape pipe -> '#?_ == "true" \|\| _== "false"' .

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
* def Test = call read ('classpath:Path/Test.xml')
* def Check = $Test/parent
* xml Downstream = "<parent></parent>"
* def desc = $Check/parent/description   
* set Downstream/parent/ind = '#?_ == "true" || _== "false"'
* set Downstream/parent/description = desc
* match $Test/parent/ind == $Downstream/parent/ind
* match $Test/parent/description == $Downstream/parent/description
```

> Note: 
>     set for XML doesn't seem to support table so use inline set.